# Finding the empirical correlation from a covariance matrix

Tags: correlation

I have this covariance matrix with five variables $X_1$ through $X_5$ in that order.

```
 6,33  1,72  1,56 -1,12 -1,03
 1,72  2,59  0,98  0,14  0,78
 1,56  0,98  3,20  0,08  0,67
-1,12  0,14  0,08  9,37 -0,89
-1,03  0,78  0,67 -0,89  6,62
```

How can I find the emipirical correlation between $X_2$ and $X_5$?

Comment: Divide $cov(x_2,x_5)$ by $\sqrt{cov(x_2,x_2)\cdot cov(x_5,x_5)}$